# Is there a magento extension that will help me split test different price points?

Tags: price, google-analytics, optimization

I was looking through the connect marketplace for a split testing extension that could help me optimize my product pricing and thus my profit per sale. To my surprise I didn't find anything.

I think it would be very useful to have a system that could test different price points for products in my store in a statistically valid way (doing this manually by changing the price a few times a week would not result in a valid test, we would need to do actual a/b split testing on the price, serving one price to visitor A and one to visitor B simultaneously).

The only thing I found was some split testing on page content (via GA and convert.com), but not on pricing as far as I can tell.

Does anyone know if there is an extension out there that I have overlooked?

Or am I the only stats freak that would want to use this?

If not, please let me know and I just might make an extension that does just that.

Thanks!

Comment: Michael, I would like to have a similar extension as well. Have you found a pre-built solution for this? (This should be a comment, but my rep is too low.)

Comment: I have not found any. I've been told this is very difficult to do in Magento because of all the caching that goes on. Since there does not seem to be much demand for this (if the views on this question are any indication), I've abandoned the idea. Let me know if you find anything though :)